# C# Error Binding Resource while Connecting to Openfire server using Jabber-Net

Tags: c#, xmpp, openfire

I am developing c# client to connect Openfire server

This is my code

```
        User = txtUserName.Text;
        Pwd = txtPassword.Text;
        pnlCredentials.Enabled = false;
        jabberClient1.User = User;
        jabberClient1.Server = "61.182.225.189";
        jabberClient1.Password = Pwd;
        jabberClient1.AutoRoster = true;

        jabberClient1.Port = 5222;

        JID jid = new JID("kamal", "192,168,1,17", "123456");



        jabberClient1.AutoLogin = true;
        jabberClient1.Resource = jid.Resource;

        jabberClient1.AutoStartTLS = true;
        jabberClient1.NetworkHost = null;
        jabberClient1.OnInvalidCertificate += new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(jabberClient1_OnInvalidCertificate);

        rm = new RosterManager();
        rm.Stream = jabberClient1;
        rm.AutoSubscribe = true;
        rm.AutoAllow = jabber.client.AutoSubscriptionHanding.AllowAll;
        rm.OnRosterBegin += new bedrock.ObjectHandler(rm_OnRosterBegin);
        rm.OnRosterEnd += new bedrock.ObjectHandler(rm_OnRosterEnd);
        rm.OnRosterItem += new RosterItemHandler(rm_OnRosterItem);


        pm = new PresenceManager();
        pm.Stream = jabberClient1;

        rosterTree1.RosterManager = rm;
        rosterTree1.PresenceManager = pm;
        rosterTree1.DoubleClick += new EventHandler(rosterTree1_DoubleClick);
        jabberClient1.OnAuthenticate += new bedrock.ObjectHandler(jabberClient1_OnAuthenticate);
        lblUser.Text = jabberClient1.User;

        jabberClient1.Connect();
```

I am not sure what I need to use  in parameters for below

JID jid = new JID("kamal", "192,168,1,17", "123456");

I used user name , server IP and password for that

when I run this it returns error

Error binding resource error type="modify" code="400"bad-requestmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"

Could you please help me to solve this

Thank you in advance

I have edited the code using the latest Jabber.net DLL as bellows

```
        JabberClient jabberClient = new JabberClient();

        //Bind the JabberClient events to methods that handle those events.
        jabberClient.OnAuthError += new IQHandler(jabberClient_OnAuthError);

        jabberClient.OnError += new bedrock.ExceptionHandler(jabberClient_OnError);
        jabberClient.OnConnect += new bedrock.ObjectHandler(jabberClient_OnConnect);
        jabberClient.OnDisconnect += new bedrock.ObjectHandler(jabberClient_OnDisconnect);

        //Set client settings
        jabberClient.AutoReconnect = 3;

        JID jid = new JID("kamal", "192.168,1,17", "123456");
        jabberClient.User = jid.User;

        jabberClient.Server = jid.Server;


        jabberClient.Port =5222;
        jabberClient.Resource = jid.Resource;
        jabberClient.Password = "123456";

        jabberClient.AutoPresence = false;
        jabberClient.AutoLogin = true;





        jabberClient.Connect();
```

Now  when I try to connect it does fire disconnect event ?

Comment: Are you using jabber.net? Is this for a web app or win app?

Comment: I am using jabber.net , that is a win app .net 4 VS  2010